# Break a Cup of His Own

Tags: possessives, ambiguity

For this sentence:

> He broke a cup of his own.

Does it mean

1. that he broke a cup of unknown ownership after someone else had broken a cup, also of unknown ownership, or
2. that, after breaking a someone else's cup, he then broke a cup that belonged to himself?

Comment: For me, it's his cup.

Comment: @DamkerngT. How about "He ate a cupcake of his own"?

Comment: It's still about his cupcake. *X of someone's own* means X belongs to that someone.

Comment: @DamkerngT. How about "He took a gamble of his own"?

Comment: Literally, he took a gamble, and that gamble was his.

Comment: @DamkerngT. So, for "break a cup of his own", "eat a cupcake of his own" and "take a chance of his own", the part "of his own" modifies the entire verb + noun, not just the noun?

Comment: It's easier to understand *an X of his own* as a thing (so if *of his own* modifies anything, it's the noun X), meaning *X belongs to him, and him alone*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. So, for "take a chance of his own", it means the chance-taking is of his own, a chance of his owning being taken?

Comment: No. It simply means "take [a chance of his own]". How you interpret how that [a chance of his own] is taken would depend on the subject of the sentence and the context. The typical subject should be that *he* himself. You can think of *He took a chance of his own.* as: He took a chance. He took it himself. The chance was of his and his alone. It belonged to no one else.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think I am confused as to whether "take a chance of his own" should be read as "take [a chance of his own]" or "[take a chance] of his own".

Comment: Ahh... I see. I think you might mix up the two patterns: "take [X of his own]" and "take X [on his own]".

Comment: @DamkerngT.  Could I then write "he kicked a bucket of his own" to mean he died after someone else had died?

Comment: It might or might not work. To *kick the bucket* is an idiom. Sometimes we can twist an idiom a bit, but chances are it will not work as expected. I think I personally won't use it myself. You can ask that as a new question too, to get more opinions from others. (A word of caution: asking opinion-based questions should be avoided, so you might need phrase your question carefully, to avoid making it sound like it's asking for opinions.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Context.

For the former case, I could say: they were arguing in the resteraunt. The first man grew so angry that he broke a cup and the other, in retaliation, broke a cup of his own.

For the latter: When he grew angry, he broke a cup of his own [because that was what he had on hand].

I prefer the former usage only because it would usually be "his own cup" rather than "a cup of his own", but perhaps this is just due to my inability to come up with a good example. Both ate reasonable interpretations.

Comment: Agreed, context makes all the difference. For the second definition, you might also say *his own cup* to emphasize the fact that he broke one owned by him after first breaking several owned by someone else.

Comment: +1 context context context, often sorts out uses that can be amibiguous

Comment: So, for "break a cup of his own", "eat a cupcake of his own" and "take a chance of his own", the part "of his own" modifies the entire verb + noun, not just the noun?

Comment: @meatie Interesting point. Yes I think it does.

Comment: @user3709296  So then, "he fell to the ground ***of his own**" is good English and means that he fell to the ground after someone else had fell to the ground?

Answer (score -1):

The possession relates to the action not the material cup. In this instance 'Breaking a cup' is a metaphor for the associated occasion that meritted the ritual cup smashing, be it mariage, an oath or promise.