# "Of His Own" Usage

Tags: prepositions, idioms, possessives, licensing

For these idioms:

1. "take a chance"
2. "kick the bucket"

"of his own" could be add to first sentence, but not the second:

> He took a chance ***of his own***.
>   He kicked the bucket ***of his own***.

I wonder why?

Comment: That's because *idioms* are used in a specific structure. However, to me, the second example better goes with *on his own* and not *of his own.*

Comment: @MaulikV *on his own* does indeed fit with *kicked the bucket*, but it means something quite different. *He kicked the bucket on his own* means *he died without any external factors contributing to the cause of death* or *he died alone*.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Yes. I meant the former one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second idiom is much more metaphorical, and *the bucket* is a single, abstract concept shared by everyone. There are not multiple buckets available to kick; there's only one, and because we're all mortal, we'll all kick it at some point. Because of this, it makes no sense to say *of his own*, because [that phrase always contrasts with a similar object owned by someone else](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26355/take-a-gamble-of-his-own?rq=1#comment49304_26357).

In the first, there are multiple *chances* available to take, and one always personally owns a chosen risk. It would be correct to say *took a chance of his own* even if that chance was compared directly against another chance of exactly the same type. For example:

> Alice checked her parachute and jumped out of the airplane. Hearing her cry of excitement, Bob decided *to take a chance of his own* and followed suit.

Alice and Bob each own their own risk, even though they're both jumping out of the same plane at more or less the same time.